# Enlarging the brightness range on Windows 11

Tags: laptop, windows-11, brightness

I am wanting to do something to make Windows 11 allow me to turn my screen brightness down further.

I have tried those brightness apps, but they mess with the gamma of the screen or use an overlay to change the brightness and that is not what I want.
I want to adjust the range that Windows 11 allow me to change my brightness and add more to the dimmer side of the range, so that I can make my screen more dim when I am in a darker environment. I know that it is Windows 11 limiting this and not my computer, because I ran a spin-off on Chrome OS from a flash drive, and it allowed me to dim my screen all the way down to practically black, and I want to be able to do that with Windows 11.

I'm not sure what my options are, or if this would be a feedback that I should share with Microsoft or if there is a tweak I can do to give me the functionality that I am looking for.

Comment: Yes; You should provide this as feedback to Microsoft within the Feedback application on your system

Comment: There are a number of third-party tools to adjust screen brightness, contrast, gamma, hue and saturation: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/software-to-adjust-monitor-brightness-and-contrast-for-dell-studio-one-desktop/ In particular, look at the OEM control panels, such as AMD, Nvidia, Intel, etc.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I know there is. I said that I've tried several of those third party tools, and they do not give me the results I am looking for. The Intel Graphics Command gives me a few options, but it is changing the brightness of the colors, not the brightness of the screen, and so everything is turning black, not just getting dimmer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get close to what you want.

Turn Main Brightness down to 0.

Turn Night Light to 100%.

I can make it so dim I cannot see the mouse pointer or much else.

If that is not dark enough, then you can use the Feedback Hub (Start, Feedback) to ask for a darker setting.

So short of turning the monitor to black on black, you can get very close.

The screen shot does not render screen brightness.

Brightness:

[image: Brightness]

Night Light:

[image]

Comment: I know I can do that, but for some reason Windows 11 on my HP computer doesn't allow me to lower the brightness that much... My sisters Lenovo laptop with Windows 11 lets her screen brightness go practically off, because it can go so low. And as I said in my question, with the spin-off of Chrome OS (I think it was called Prime OS), it let me dim my screen _way_ lower than what it does now. I just want to know if there is any way I can modify the range that it currently allows me

Comment: Ask HP Support. What you see is a manufacturer's issue, not a Windows issue. As noted I can go so dim I cannot read the display.